# Multi Checkbox Filter in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-filter

**Need to solve Multi checkbox filter for Search Module With All Results**

Here is the working Code for Search with one checkbox

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    var json = {
        "modules": [{
            "myid": "70",
            "realname": "Kishore",
            "full_name": "Kishore Chandra",
            "category": "professional",
            "firm_name": "Yes",
            "designation": "Design-Build Firm",
            "address": "Dwarakanagar 5th lane"
        }, {
            "myid": "75",
            "realname": "Vinod kumar",
            "full_name": "Kishore Chandra",
            "category": "professional",
            "firm_name": "",
            "designation": null,
            "address": null
        }, {
            "myid": "76",
            "realname": "Pradeep Reddy",
            "full_name": "PRADEEP REDDY",
            "category": "professional",
            "firm_name": "",
            "designation": "Civil Engineer",
            "address": "Visakapatnam, Andhra Pradesh, India"
        }, {
            "myid": "78",
            "realname": "Pradeep Raju",
            "full_name": "",
            "category": "professional",
            "firm_name": "",
            "designation": null,
            "address": null
        }, {
            "myid": "79",
            "realname": "Pradeep kumar",
            "full_name": "",
            "category": "professional",
            "firm_name": "",
            "designation": null,
            "address": null
        }, {
            "myid": "80",
            "realname": "Pradeep",
            "full_name": "Pradeep",
            "category": "professional",
            "firm_name": "",
            "designation": "Architect",
            "address": "Akkayapalem"
        }, {
            "myid": "81",
            "realname": "Pradeep",
            "full_name": "Pradeep Reddy ",
            "category": "professional",
            "firm_name": "",
            "designation": "Civil Engineer",
            "address": "Jubliee Hills"
        }, {
            "myid": "82",
            "realname": "krishna",
            "full_name": "",
            "category": "professional",
            "firm_name": "",
            "designation": null,
            "address": null
        }, {
            "myid": "83",
            "realname": "raghu",
            "full_name": "",
            "category": "professional",
            "firm_name": "",
            "designation": null,
            "address": null
        }, {
            "myid": "84",
            "realname": "Pradeep",
            "full_name": "",
            "category": "professional",
            "firm_name": "",
            "designation": null,
            "address": null
        }, {
            "myid": "85",
            "realname": "Pradeep",
            "full_name": "",
            "category": "professional",
            "firm_name": "",
            "designation": null,
            "address": null
        }, {
            "myid": "86",
            "realname": "Pradeep",
            "full_name": "",
            "category": "professional",
            "firm_name": "",
            "designation": null,
            "address": null
        }, {
            "myid": "87",
            "realname": "Pradeep",
            "full_name": "",
            "category": "professional",
            "firm_name": "",
            "designation": null,
            "address": null
        }, {
            "myid": "88",
            "realname": "Pradeep",
            "full_name": "",
            "category": "professional",
            "firm_name": "",
            "designation": null,
            "address": null
        }, {
            "myid": "89",
            "realname": "Pradeep",
            "full_name": "",
            "category": "professional",
            "firm_name": "",
            "designation": null,
            "address": null
        }, {
            "myid": "72",
            "realname": "recobee",
            "full_name": "Kishore Chandra",
            "category": "vendor",
            "firm_name": "Recobee",
            "designation": "Hardware",
            "address": "55-2-27\/1, Old Venkojipalem, Near Andhra Bank, Hb Colony Road"
        }, {
            "myid": "90",
            "realname": "Vinod kumar",
            "full_name": "Tiles Vendor",
            "category": "vendor",
            "firm_name": "Vendor1",
            "designation": "Tiles",
            "address": "akkayapalem, "
        }, {
            "myid": "92",
            "realname": "Vamsi Vytla",
            "full_name": "vamsi vytla",
            "category": "vendor",
            "firm_name": "vytla cements",
            "designation": "Cement Suppliers",
            "address": "akkayapalem"
        }, {
            "myid": "93",
            "realname": "Bhaskar",
            "full_name": "Surya Bhaskar",
            "category": "vendor",
            "firm_name": "Talatam",
            "designation": "Doors and Windows",
            "address": "Hitech city"
        }, {
            "myid": "94",
            "realname": "Naren",
            "full_name": "Naren Mandala",
            "category": "vendor",
            "firm_name": "Mandala Hardwares",
            "designation": "Hardware",
            "address": "Malleshwaram road"
        }, {
            "myid": "95",
            "realname": "Sreetej",
            "full_name": "Sreetej Vincent",
            "category": "vendor",
            "firm_name": "Vincent Paints",
            "designation": "Paintings",
            "address": "Navi Mumbai"
        }, {
            "myid": "96",
            "realname": "Raja",
            "full_name": "Ramesh Raja Galla",
            "category": "vendor",
            "firm_name": "Galla plumbing ",
            "designation": "Plumbing & Bathware",
            "address": "Karol Bagh "
        }, {
            "myid": "97",
            "realname": "Prasanna kumar",
            "full_name": "Prasanna kumar",
            "category": "vendor",
            "firm_name": "JP cement",
            "designation": "Cement Suppliers",
            "address": "poonamalle road"
        }, {
            "myid": "98",
            "realname": "Phalgun",
            "full_name": "Phalgun Moturu",
            "category": "vendor",
            "firm_name": "Moturu Tiles",
            "designation": "Tiles",
            "address": "benz circle"
        }, {
            "myid": "99",
            "realname": "Pavan",
            "full_name": "Pavan kumar",
            "category": "vendor",
            "firm_name": "Pavan Constructions",
            "designation": "Cement Suppliers",
            "address": "Jubliee hills"
        }]
    };

    $scope.ocw = json;

    var allCategories = json.modules.map(function(item) {
        return item.designation
    });
    var filteredCategories = [];


    allCategories.forEach(function(item) {
        if (filteredCategories.indexOf(item) < 0 && item) {
            filteredCategories.push(item);
        }
    });

    $scope.search = {
        designation: ""
    }

    $scope.categories = filteredCategories;

    $scope.isFiltered = function(val) {
        return $scope.search.designations[val.designation];
    }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>
        document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.15"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <form>
        <div ng-repeat="designation in categories">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="search.designations[designation]"> {{designation}}
        </div>
        Full name: <input type="text" ng-model="search.full_name">
    </form>
    <table class="table table-bordered" ng-repeat="module in ocw.modules | filter:isFiltered | filter:{full_name:search.full_name}">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <h3 class="moduletitle">Name : {{ module.realname }}</h3>
                <p>Designation : {{ module.designation }}</p>
                <p>Category : {{ module.category }}</p>
                <p>Fullname : {{ module.full_name }}</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>

</html>
```

---

Working Code  But Need **All Results** Before Filtering

http://plnkr.co/edit/QNS5iX3atZ8C7lrG1gyU?p=preview

Comment: Like this: http://plnkr.co/edit/S6QXuD0eYMqBTXgoLAri?p=info

Comment: Thank you for the answer it is working perfectly now. and how to have All results.. (Check box All for getting all results)

Comment: I got the Solution for that this is the Solved Link  http://plnkr.co/edit/QNS5iX3atZ8C7lrG1gyU?p=preview